# Why did LED lit up while soldering?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, light-emitting-diodes

I was soldering an LED when accidentally the soldering wire touched the LED's other Pin while the soldering iron was touching the other and the LED lit up, not bright but bright enough to be seen.

I did it again to see did it actually light up, and it did. I noticed my bare feet were touching the ground so I raised it to observe, the LED got dim.
Another thing I observed was that no matter what pin (cathode or anode) touched what (soldering iron or soldering wire), it lit up.

1. Why did it lit up?
   I know that heat causes particles (electrons in this case) to move (kinetic molecular theory), but does it move enough to make an LED light up? As a diode it has a voltage value after it allows current to flow, was the heat enough to make it past that limiting voltage? (I don't remember the actual term).
2. Why did the polarity not matter?
   I have no clue about this. LED like any other diode is biased means allowing current flow in one direction, than why does this happen? Does the electron movement not matter in this case?

Comment: Your soldering iron has a leakage current, most likely AC, which is consistent with the polarity being irrelevant. I would take a multimeter and check... and probably abstain from using it on sensitive parts.

Comment: I fully agree with @CuriousOne, but would go even further - a good soldering iron should not have this leakage current, and should it increase it could pose a hazard to you. Buy a nice new one. For now, use a GFI plug adapter while using the old one...

Comment: On second thought I fully agree with Jon Custer on this one... one can't rule the safety hazard out and I would issue the same warning. One can't be cautious enough.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the diode lit for both ways of connecting your finger and soldering tip to the diode, the soldering tip has an AC voltage on it, and one side of the AC is connected to your building ground (the floor your bare feet were touching).  The solder tip is heated by a coil for which it sounds like has 120 VAC on it.  There is a short through the insulation of that coil (< few  10 Kohms of resistance) to the solder tip.  Your feet must also have < few 10 Kohms ground.  This would provide the ~mA to light the diode.

You are lucky you didn't get a shock.  Measure the voltage between your solder tip and a water pipe in your house with an AC voltmeter.  You probably need a new soldering iron.

PS: Good description and wonderful experimental method in checking both polarities ... but like some of the great scientists of history you risked your life !!  About 15 mA through your chest would have put your heart into fibrillation.

Comment: Wow... like seriously wow... thanks everyone... i need to retire my 6 yr old solder then... I think it time... thanks for the safety advice. I never thought about leakage current. BTW i tried it with volt meter before your reply it was 70 mV. Didn't try the current (i never do)